# How to find m by given information.

Tags: geometry

If the chord $y=mx+1$ of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ subtends an angle of measure $45^o$ at the major segment of the circle then m= . How to find m.

Comment: What is the major segment of the circle?

Comment: A drawing would help to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given, there are 2 lines that fit the description.

[image]

If the angle subtended at the major segment is $45^0$, then the angle subtended at the center is $90^0$.